# Using Mage register when submitting values with ajax to controller

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I am trying to pass data from a controller to be used in the view.  What is happening is I am taking super attributes for the product that user selects (size and color) and all of that gets serialized and passed to the controller where I get a product object. From this object I am then able to get the configurable sku which I then need to echo out into the design view.phtml file.

The function in the controller looks like :

```
if($product = $this->_initProduct())
        {
           $config = $product->getSku();
          // if I echo $config here using firephp I can see that this is correct value
           Mage::register('config_product', $config);
          // I am hoping to set it as a global variable here that 
          //  I can then retrieve on the success of the ajax function
        }
```

In the phtml I have something like this to send form values to that controller :

```
 var data = $("#product_addtocart_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/locator/item/index",
                data: data
            }).done(function(){
                <?php $currentProduct = Mage::registry('config_product'); 
                 // Why does this return blank??
                 ?>
                 <?php Mage::helper('firephp')->send( $currentProduct ); ?>                    
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP and JavaScript can't be used together like that. PHP is used on the web server and JavaScript is installed in the clients browser (IE,Chrome,etc..)

In your controller you'll want to echo a JSON encoded string and in your javascript add dataType to the .ajax function:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/locator/item/index",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json'
        },function(returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData);                   
        });
```

And open your js console in your browser to inspect the data returned.

Comment: Thanks I have tried that but I just get an empty string.  Can you please elaborate on what the controller should look like based on my above example?  I just tried adding `return json_encode($config)`

Comment: Ahh durp... Wunderbar!  Thanks!